# R: Adding a row to my dataframe with the medians of each column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a row to my dataframe with the medians of all the colums. So if we have this dataset:

```
        GDP    GDP per capita
France   1      1   
Spain    1      1
Etiopia  3      3
```

I would like to add a row called "Medians", so the dataframe ends up like this:

```
         GDP    GDP per capita
France   1      1   
Spain    1      1
Etiopia  3      3
Medians  1      1
```

I think I should use rbind() and colMeans(), but I'm not sure how should I code it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `data.frame`, then can loop over the columns with `sapply`

```
df1 <- rbind(df1, Medians = sapply(df1, median, na.rm = TRUE))
df1
#         GDP GDP per capita
#France    1              1
#Spain     1              1
#Etiopia   3              3
#Medians   1              1
```

If it is a `matrix`, `apply` with `MARGIN = 2` can be used (it also works with `data.frame`)

```
rbind(df1, Medians = apply(df1, 2, median, na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GDP = c(1L, 1L, 3L), `GDP per capita` = c(1L, 
1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("France", "Spain", 
"Etiopia"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting NA results because some cells has NA values, I guess I should add na.rm, but where?

Comment: Thanks! Now I've got the median of just one column, the others I get "NA", and the error: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" repeated several times.

Comment: @Jusep Can you check the `str(df1)`. Is it `numeric` or other types?

Comment: str(df1) shows me that all the columns are chr, character strings I guess. Maybe I should convert them in numeric values right?

Comment: @Jusep Yes, if the columns should be numeric and it is character, you can convert them.  Can you try `df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)` if there are no character elements on those columns, this will automaticlaly convert to numeric

Comment: @Jusep If you want to convert all the columns to character by force, an option is `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.numeric)` assuming all columns are character and they should be numeric